# Significance in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

Ok, this is quite hard to explain, but I'm at a complete loss what to do. I'm a relative newcomer to R and although I can completely admire how powerful it is, I'm not too good at actually using it....

Basically, I have some very contrived data that I need to analyse (it wasn't me who chose this, I can assure you!). I have the right and left hand lengths of lots of people, as well as some numeric data that shows their sociability.

Now I would like to know if people who have significantly different lengths of hand are more or less sociable than those who have the same (leading into the research that 'symmetrical' people are more sociable and intelligent, etc.

I have got as far as loading the data into R, then I have no idea where to go from there. How on Earth do I start to separate those who are close to symmetrical to those who aren't to then start to do the analysis?

---

Ok, using Sacha's great advice, I did the cor.test and got the following:

```
Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  measurements$l.hand - measurements$r.hand and measurements$sociable 
t = 0.2148, df = 150, p-value = 0.8302
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1420623  0.1762437 
sample estimates:
       cor 
0.01753501
```

I have never used this test before, so am unsure how to intepret it...you wouldn't think I was on my fourth Scientific degree would you?! :(

Comment: Can you not create a third variable that is the differnece in hand length for each person and then regress that against sociability / intelligence etc.?

Comment: This is quickly become a question not about R, but about statistics. That's OK, but for future reference you might look into http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the broader scheme of things, sure, yes, it's fine.  However, many questions like this dilute the utility of stackoverflow by reducing its tight on programming questions.

Comment: A significance test can only tell you if the result is *not* due to random error.

Answer (score 1):

A significance test is used to see if the aquired effect in the sample can be due to random error. It is not really usable for individual scores, but what you can do is standardize the differences.

If 'dat' is the name of your dataframe, containing the columns 'hand.left', 'hand.right' and 'social' then you can standardize the differences in this way:

```
stand=scale(dat$hand.left-dat$hand.right)
```

Then you can create a logical dummy vector indicating if a person has a likelihood of this difference given the sample:

```
dum=abs(stand)<1.96
```

Which you can then use in a t-test:

```
t.test(dat$social[dum],dat$social[!dum])
```

However, the problem with this is that due to the nature of standardizing the sample size in the equal hand group will be about 20 times larger then the inequal hand group, so you need a lot of observations. An alternative is to look at the correlation between sociability and the absolute hand differences:

```
cor.test(abs(dat$hand.left-dat$hand.right), dat$social)
```

Comment: Wow, it actually worked without spitting errors out at me! I have a question though (which could be blindingly obvious): why did you use 1.96? Can you use any number? This is what I really struggle with in R, making the fake vectors- I just can't get my head around it. I did the cor.test and it worked, but I've never used it before- I'm off to search for some more info! Thanks again, you're amazing!

Comment: What Sacha did with scale is a standardization. It creates stand which has a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. So if the 1.96 does not look familiar (1.96 standard deviations == 95th percentile), then it's time to brush up on some statistics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: Aaaaah, of course it is! Sorry for posting in the wrong section. I used to be so good at stats, but R has destroyed me! :(

Comment: @Sacha : significant difference is not the same as statistically significant and is not the same as "in the 5% most extreme values". Using your approach, you just select the 5% most extreme values of difference, whatever that is. That's not how to do it.

Comment: @Joris : You're right. This is just a way to divide the sample in two groups using an arbitrary number of standard deviations as cutoff score. It also should not again be centered I see now, so use scale(dat$hand.left-dat$hand.right, center=FALSE) instead. Using the 1.96 as cutoff selects only the 5% most extreme cases as the second group, another option would be to use 1 (1 standard deviation). I prefer the correlation though.

Comment: (How do you add a comment to the original question?)  That result means there is no lineair relation between the difference between left and right hand and sociability. However I see that that is not really what you are interested in. If you take the absolute values of those differences you get a measure of how much the hand sizes differ cor(abs(dat$hand.left - dat$hand.right), dat$social)

Comment: @Sacha: Get a bit more reputation (you need 50), and you'll be able to do so. See also the FAQ. Given your proficiency in R, that shouldn't bee too difficult.

Comment: Replace `1.96` with `qnorm(0.975)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a regression problem:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(lhand = rnorm(100, 15, sd = 2), rhand = rnorm(100, 15, sd = 2),
                 social = runif(100))
DF <- within(DF, handedness <- lhand - rhand)

mod <- lm(social ~ handedness, data = DF)
summary(mod)
```

Here this is no relationship (not suprising as these are just random data):

```
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = social ~ handedness, data = DF)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.51113 -0.25170 -0.02336  0.26161  0.52042 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.507240   0.030700  16.522   <2e-16 ***
handedness  -0.007896   0.011670  -0.677      0.5    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.3051 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.00465,    Adjusted R-squared: -0.005506 
F-statistic: 0.4579 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.5002
```

For your real problem, ask yourself if a linear approximation between social and handedness might be appropriate. So plot the data:

```
plot(social ~ handedness, data = DF)
```

Does it look bivariate Gaussian?

If the linear relationship looks OK, fit the linear model and then check the residuals for problems (curved patterns, non-constant variance, strong deviation from normality). Then move on from there. If a linear approximation doesn't seem right, can you linearise the relationship with a transformation? If yes, try that, if not how about trying a GLM? etc. etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for replying-it's very much appreciated! This looks similar to what we did in the lab so I'll have a look.

Comment: It's maybe worth looking at `abs(lhand - rhand)` too to see if ambidextrousness affects sociality.

Answer (score 0):

You should examine your data...

```
hist( measurements$social )
```

How does it look?... normal?

You might try regression

```
stand = scale( measurements$l.hand - measurements$r.hand )
m <- lm( measurements$social ~ stand )
m
summary(m)
anova(m)
```

You can also plot the model and it will give you diagnostics

```
plot(m)
```

*Please type the phrase ?command (e.g. ?lm) for all of the commands that you try here.  It will help you understand what is going on.*

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the univariate normality of the response. Its is the normality of the coefficients that we worry about, and that can be investigated by looking at the normality of the model residuals. If these are approximately normal or don't deviate too strongly from normality then we can stop worrying. Thanks in part to the central limit theorem.

Comment: I'm just encouraging looking at the data.  I've fixed my mistaken omission of examining the diagnostic plots of the model.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm very appreciative!